# Как правильно отправить Storage::download() так, чтобы потом использовать фото на странице Laravel?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

На Laravel в storage/app есть файл 12.png, как отправить его в ответе запроса, для дальнейшего использования? Помогите кто-нибудь...

Comment: `return response()->download($pathToFile);` А что значит _чтоб потом использовать фото на странице_? Напишите что и как делаете и что хотите сделать

Comment: на сервере есть фото(находится в storage/app). Я хочу отправить его пользователю, как ответ на запрос, а затем вывести его как <img src = ''>

Comment: но не знаю как, ибо когда я возвращаю return response()->download($pathToFile); возвращается лишь headers: {}

Comment: Создайте ссылку в папке public на папку где хранится фото и вы в src просто путь прописываете к файлу + имя файла, а возвращать ничего не надо